# Vertical labeled text is not shows center align on first time display

Tags: html, css, asp.net, internet-explorer

I am working on Asp project. while testing found some strange problem that while first time loading the Label text is not aligned as per the values in CSS.

But even if I do some zoom operation, the text shows center align.
This problem is happen when opening the site in compatible mode in Internet Explorer.

Can any one please tell me why it is happening?

The CSS is :

```
.VerticalText {
            writing-mode: tb-rl;
            text-align: center; 
            overflow: auto; 
}
```

The label declaration is:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblRecordDetails" 
           runat="server" 
           Height="540px" 
           Text="FDARecordDetails" 
           Width="19px" 
           CssClass="VerticalText"
           Font-Bold="True" 
           Font-Names="Verdana" 
           Font-Size="9pt" 
           BorderColor="White" 
           BackColor="#FF8000">
</asp:Label>
```

PLease let me know if any more information is needed..

Comment: IE? could you try adding `zoom:1.0` to the CSS rule? Hopefully it will trigger `hasLayout` and fix the problem. Cheers!

Comment: @potatopeelings I have tried with your suggestion but its not working for me. Still the text is not center align at very first loading

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to replicate it. Would you be able to copy the generated HTML into a fiddle and see if the problem still exists?

Comment: @potatopeelings can u try after ading the site into compatible mode in IE? I m facing issue when using compatible mode for the site